# Cells display content from previous cells and sometime crashes

Tags: ios, uitableview, instance

I have problem with a UITableview, I'm fetching some data and displaying it in a custom cell views, almost everything is going well except two issues :

- When I scroll down, some new cells show content from previous cells (especially the **TextView cellText**)
- sometime the app crashes with **[UIImageView setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance** at line :
  [cellText setText:postText];

Here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath method :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   


NSString *PostCellIdentifier;

Post *info = [posts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *PostType = info.type;

if([PostType isEqualToString:@"quote"]) {

    PostCellIdentifier = @"NewsQuoteCell";

} else if([PostType isEqualToString:@"article"]) {

    PostCellIdentifier = @"NewsArticleCell";

} else if([PostType isEqualToString:@"picture"]) {

    PostCellIdentifier = @"NewsPictureCell";

} else if([PostType isEqualToString:@"video"]) {

    PostCellIdentifier = @"NewsVideoCell";

} else if([PostType isEqualToString:@"audio"]) {

    PostCellIdentifier = @"NewsAudioCell";

}    


NewsQuoteCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PostCellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[NewsQuoteCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:PostCellIdentifier];
}



UILabel *cellLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
[cellLabel setText:info.masjid_name];

UILabel *cellDate = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
[cellDate setText:info.date];


UITextView *cellText = (UITextView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:5];
NSString *postText = info.title;
[postText stringByDecodingHTMLEntities];    
if ([postText length] > 300) { 
    postText = [postText substringToIndex:300];
    postText = [postText stringByAppendingString:@"..."];
}
[cellText setText:postText];

CGRect frame = cellText.frame;
frame.size.height = cellText.contentSize.height;
cellText.frame = frame;


UIImageView *cellImage = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3];
NSString *imagePath = info.masjid_thumb;
[cellImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", imagePath]]];

cell.backgroundView = [ [UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"news_bg"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 0, 10, 0)] ];  
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [ [UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"news_bg"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 0, 10, 0)] ];






if([PostType isEqualToString:@"article"]) {


    cellText.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *pgrText = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                       initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapArticle:)];
    [cellText setTag:indexPath.row];
    [cellText addGestureRecognizer:pgrText];



    UIImageView *cellMedia = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:10];

    cellMedia.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *pgr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                   initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapArticle:)];
    [cellMedia setTag:indexPath.row];
    [cellMedia addGestureRecognizer:pgr];

} else if ([PostType isEqualToString:@"video"]) {


    cellText.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *pgrText = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                       initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    [cellText setTag:indexPath.row];
    [cellText addGestureRecognizer:pgrText];



    UIImageView *cellMedia = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:10];

    cellMedia.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *pgr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                   initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    [cellMedia setTag:indexPath.row];
    [cellMedia addGestureRecognizer:pgr];


} else if ([PostType isEqualToString:@"audio"]) {


    cellText.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *pgrText = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                       initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    [cellText setTag:indexPath.row];
    [cellText addGestureRecognizer:pgrText];


    UIImageView *cellMedia = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:10];

    cellMedia.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *pgr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                   initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    [cellMedia setTag:indexPath.row];
    [cellMedia addGestureRecognizer:pgr];


} else if ([PostType isEqualToString:@"picture"]) {

    cellText.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    cellText.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f);
    cellText.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5f;
    cellText.layer.shadowRadius = 0.5f;

    UIImageView *cellMedia = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:7];

    NSString *mediaPath = info.media;


   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:mediaPath]];
    AFImageRequestOperation *operation = [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(UIImage *image) {

        UIImage* scaled2 = [image scaleToFitSize:(CGSize){284, 284}];
        [cellMedia setImage:scaled2];

        CGRect frame1 = cellMedia.frame;
        frame1.size.width = 284;
        frame1.size.height = scaled2.size.height;
        cellMedia.frame = frame1;

    }];
    [operation start];



    cellMedia.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *pgr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                   initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapPicture:)];
    [cellMedia setTag:indexPath.row];
    [cellMedia addGestureRecognizer:pgr];




    if ([postText length] > 300) { 
        postText = [postText substringToIndex:300];
        postText = [postText stringByAppendingString:@"..."];
    }
    [cellText setText:postText];

    CGRect frame = cellText.frame;

    frame.size.height = cellText.contentSize.height;
    frame.origin.y = cellMedia.frame.origin.y + (cellMedia.frame.size.height - cellText.contentSize.height);
   cellText.frame = frame;

}


return cell;


}
```

Any help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a subclass of UITableViewCell called NewsQuoteCell.  You can override the prepareForReuse method in the NewsQuoteCell class to fix your new cell shows content of previous cell issue.  The other issue seemed to have to do with the your tag for view number 5 was not a UITextView but a UIImageView.  I would double check your NewsQuoteCell's implementation file.

Comment: Yes it's a subclasse of UITableViewCell but I don't do anything in it. What is the best way ? doing everything in cellForRowAtIndexPath or override prepareForReuse in the NewsQuoteCell ? I have 5 different custom cells by the way (quote, article, video, audio and picture). I have to create a subclasse foreach one or code everything in cellForRowAtIndexPath ?

Comment: I still have to fix the first issue. I noticed that only cellText and cellMedia (for pictures) use old content and not the others.

Comment: I found the problem, it was due to this line [cellText setTag:indexPath.row] ....

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have created `NewsQuoteCell` in a seperate nib file. If thats the case why dont you setup proper `IBOutlet`s to bind different components like the cellLabel, cellDate, cellText etc. That way you don't have to retrieve these components using `viewWithTag`.

And you are probably doing something funny with the tag. Have you setup the tags properly? One definite problem is your second error message. You are retrieving a `UIImageView` with the `viewWithTag` call and referencing it with `UITextView`. Make sure that tags are set up properly. And it never hurts to set the tag values to something unique, like 101, 102,103... etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't know why but changing the Tag in the storyboard from 5 to 105 fixed the problem ... weird ... The tag references a Text View from the beginning this is why i don't understand why my app crashes.

Comment: But I still have to fix the first issue. I noticed that only cellText and cellMedia (for pictures) use old content and not the others.

Comment: I found the problem, it was due to this line [cellText setTag:indexPath.row] ....